# Optional string input when following string inputs are not optional?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am trying to implement an interface as a service controller. I do not maintain this interface, so I am unable to modify it. For simplicity, let's say the interface looks like this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Bar(string A, int B);
}
```

For my controller, let's say it looks like this:

```
public class FooController : ApiController, IFoo
{
    [Route("~/Foo/Bar")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Bar(string optionalA, int requiredB)
    {
        return DoStuff(optionalA, requiredB);
    }
}
```

With this setup, how can I decorate `A` as Optional and `B` as Required without changing `IFoo` (i.e. cannot reorder A and B) and while still having my controller implement IFoo? By default, all string parameters are considered Required unless I pull them into a class at which point they revert to defaulting to Optional unless I decorate them with a `RequiredAttribute` but I cannot do that here because that would require either changing `IFoo` or would break my requirement to implement `IFoo` with this controller class.

Is there a straight up way to do this in a way that Swagger & Swagger UI honors it? I'd like to avoid this hacky solution:

```
public class FooController : ApiController, IFoo
{
    [Route("~/Foo/Bar")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string FakeBar(MyDto data)
    {
        return Bar(data.optionalA, data.requiredB);
    }

    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    public string Bar(string optionalA, int requiredB)
    {
        return DoStuff(optionalA, requiredB);
    }
}

public class MyDto
{
    // defaults to optional here
    public string optionalA { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int requiredB { get; set; }
}
```

I do understand that if I could reorder A and B (that's not an option) then the simple solution is this:

```
public string Bar(int requiredB, string optionalA = null)
```

Comment: Hacky solution should work. you can also do this which is more or less the same thing `public string FakeBar(int requiredB, string optionalA = null )
    {
        return Bar(optionalA, requiredB);
    }`

Comment: when you call a web API from JS or some other client, you are setting the values for the argument by name. right? so why is the order of the arguments in the Web API method significant? You should be able to put your optional parameters at the end like C# requires without having an impact on the caller of your API

Comment: @GlennFerrie If I do that, then I no longer am implementing IFoo with this Controller class.

Comment: @Nkosi The hacky solution greatly increases the complexity of the code to maintain (as I stated in the original question, I'd like to avoid that). I changed a data type to int for the required parameter to elaborate why I cannot change the order myself while still implementing IFoo.

Comment: You can explicitly implement IFoo and adjust your API parameters

Comment: @Jaxidian Forcing your controllers (UI concerns) to implement interface is what greatly increases the complexity, which you have already discovered. IFoo should be an inject-able service to your controller.

Comment: @Nkosi I don't want to debate the decision to have my controller implement an interface. I'd like to have an answer to my question while avoiding the hacky solution I also put into the question. I think a different way to ask the question is: Can I accomplish this with a standard or custom attribute of some sort?

Comment: @Jaxidian, Only other option is to create an action filter specific to the action that would enforce what you want based on request parameters. `[MyFilter( Optional = "optionalA")]` either opt in or opt out model. the filter can either allow request throw based on rule or return bad request or not found

Comment: @Nkosi I think that will work and would be more preferable (I have quite a few of these and this keeps it easy). Would you mind writing that up as an answer and pointing me somewhere concrete to get started (base classes and how to hook up the filter)?

Comment: @Jaxidian, I am not in a position to write it up now. but can do it later if it is not pressing for you.

Comment: @nkosi That's fine. Thank you!

Comment: @Jaxidian check out this article and see if you want to go down this route. https://blog.markvincze.com/how-to-validate-action-parameters-with-dataannotation-attributes/ I tried it out with some integration tests and the deeper i go the more i have to add the having to go through all this song and dance to compensate for poor design is not worth it in the end. I would have posted the answer but it would have included my opposition to the design and I would rather avoid the down votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that I am unable to accomplish this. I am forced to either change the interface or not implement the interface or some other nasty thing that causes way too much additional code. At this time, I think there is just no other way to directly control the requiredness of a parameter to an action handler.

Will gladly defer to anybody who corrects me though! ;-)